# Struct pointer becomes NULL at every function call

Tags: c, memory, struct

I faced to a problem about to make "Sets" with struct on C.

I had initialized two struct pointers(S1, S2).
At first time to initialize the pointers and print there address with %p has work, but after to access the functions with S2, It doesn't work.
I checked pointer after access the function. Address of S2 became a NULL.
I don't know how can I fix this problem..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define defaultSize 5

typedef enum {FALSE, TRUE} Boolean;

typedef struct {
    int nElements;
    int arraySize;
    char **element;
} strset_t;

strset_t *createSet()
{
    strset_t *s;
    if((s = (strset_t*)malloc(sizeof(strset_t))) != NULL){
        s->element = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * defaultSize);

        s->nElements = 0;
        s->arraySize = defaultSize;
    }

    return s;
}

void deleteSet(strset_t *s)
{
    free(s->element);
    free(s);
}

int cardinality(strset_t *s)
{
    return s->nElements;
}

int isElement(char *x, strset_t *a)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < a->nElements; i++)
        if(strcmp(x, a->element[i]) == 0)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

Boolean addElement(char *x, strset_t *a)
{
    if(a->nElements == a->arraySize){
        a->arraySize *= 2;
        a = realloc(a, a->arraySize);

        puts("== extended ==");
    }

    if(a == NULL){
        puts("=== NULL ===");
        return FALSE;
    }

    a->element[a->nElements] = (char *)malloc(strlen(x) + 1);
    strcpy(a->element[a->nElements], x);
    a->nElements++; //deep copy를 사용하여 값 전달

    return TRUE;
}

Boolean removeElement(char *x, strset_t *a)
{
    int idx = isElement(x, a);

    if(idx == -1){
        puts("=== Not found ===");
        return FALSE;
    }

    for(int i = idx; i < a->nElements - 1; i++){
        free(a->element[i]);
        a->element[i] = a->element[i + 1];
    }

    free(a->element[a->nElements - 1]);
    a->nElements--;
}

int main()
{
    strset_t *S1, *S2;

    S1 = createSet();
    S2 = createSet();

    Boolean run = TRUE;

    char target, selection;
    char buff[100];

    while(run){
        printf("%p %p\n", S1, S2);

        fflush(stdin);

        switch (getchar()) {
        case '1':
            printf("Target(1, 2)) : ");
            scanf("%d", &target);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Element : ");
            if(target == 1)
                addElement(gets(buff), S1);
            else if(target == 2)
                addElement(gets(buff), S2);

            break;

        case '2':
            printf("Target(1, 2)) : ");
            scanf("%d", &target);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Element : ");
            if(target == 1)
                removeElement(gets(buff), S1);
            else if(target == 2)
                removeElement(gets(buff), S2);

            break;

        case 'X':
            run = FALSE;
            break;

        default:
            puts("== Invalid menu ==");
            getchar();
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    deleteSet(S1);
    deleteSet(S2);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A struct cannot become NULL. A pointer can.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala yup my mistake, I mean, struct pointer be a NULL pointer everytime. thanks I'll modify my post

Comment: 1) Never use gets, is no longer part of the language, instead use `fgets` and strip the trailing `'\0'`  2) `"%p"` wants a cast: `(void *)S1`

Comment: What input do you give your program? How do you know that the pointer becomes null? After every function call of *what*?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &target);` - it requires an **`int`** yet `target` is a `char`.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Thanks! I will fix my habbit.

Comment: Also, C99 has a perfectly fine `bool` type available when you `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: The switch getchar() is bad too, if you hit enter at first it gets totally out of sync.

Comment: [32, 33) 'target' <== Memory access at offset 33 overflows this variable
    [96, 196) 'buff'

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 1) char * type(String) will given 2) I checked with 'if(a == NULL)' now It's not on my code on this post 3) every functions that i made. hmm.. I need to modify my post to be specific

Comment: Did you change `target` to an `int`yet

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OMG you're correct. I tried to change char to int, finally I got success to access the functions. thanks. and say again thanks you to notice me the bad habbit to write the code.

Comment: Use a proper compiler like GCC (you can use the online version at Godbolt if not anything else) and compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` or similar. And never use `gets`. There is no `gets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addElement()` the call of `realloc()` gets as size only `a->arraySize` but you need `sizeof(char *) * a->arraySize` as on the call of `malloc()`. The allocated block will be smaller than before (because `sizeof(char *)` is greater than 1, depending on your system) and when writing into it other memory will be overwritten.

Comment: ohhh I had mistakes. Thanks!